# How do I keep HDD from turning off?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, battery

I have a laptop with an SSD and HDD. Windows is installed on the SSD, but because the SSD only has 250GB some of the larger programs are installed on the HDD. My problem is, when I'm using one of those programs if I leave it alone for a few minutes and then go back there is an annoying period of a few seconds that I have to wait before the program responds, because the disk is starting to spin. I already went to battery setting and set for the disk to never turn off, but I think it only works for the disk where the OS is installed. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Some hard disks have a built-in system that spins down the disk when not used, independently from what is configured in Windows.

Some years ago I successfully used a utility called quietHDD ([link](https://sites.google.com/site/quiethdd/)) to stop the disk from spinning down. Just set the APM (Advanced Power Management) setting to what you prefer.

Comment: Or try KeepAliveHD, https://github.com/stsrki/keepalivehd

Comment: @DrMoishePippik the software you suggested works also with USB drives that doesn't allow the ATA commands used by quietHDD